# Ruby: How do I view the error message detailing a program crash?

Tags: ruby, crash

When I run a Ruby program with an error in it, the console output appears for only a splitsecond. It is impossible for me to read the reason why it crashed. Is there any way I can get the console to hang around for a bit longer? Or alternatively save the crash message to a text file?

Comment: Why is the console not hanging around? The error crashes the console?

Comment: Need more info. Which OS are you running it on. How are you trying to run the ruby program. And What ruby program is it - is it one that you created